# Green's function of a Markov Chain, and maybe of a Feller Process?

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, markov-chains

How are the Green's functions of a Markov chain related to the notion from PDE theory?

For instance, if the Markov chain (i.e. discrete state space) is continuous time, then the Green's function I'm thinking of is $G(x, y)=\int_0^\infty p_t(x, y)dt$ where $p_t$ is the transition kernel.

Is there a reasonable notion of the green's "function" when you have a Feller process instead of a Markov chain? (So now instead of transition functions, you have semigroups, and instead of Q matrices one has a generator.)

Answer (score 2):

> How are the Green's functions of a Markov chain related to the notion from PDE theory?

These are the same: the Green function of a Markov chain is the Green function "from PDE theory" associated to its generator.

> Is there a reasonable notion of the (G)reen's "function" when you have a Feller process instead of a Markov chain?

Indeed there is, with no scare quotes. For an introduction, see Liggett's book *Continuous Time Markov Processes: An Introduction*, especially chapter 3.

Comment: How is the Green's function defined for our situation, where the domain of our PDE is $[0, \infty)\times S\times S$ where $S$ is the state space of the Markov Chain, or $[0, \infty)\times S$ when $S$ is the state space of a Feller process?  Maybe you can tell that I don't really know how to even get a set up in which it would make sense to say "Green's function."  The reasons for this are that the space is not Euclidean, so I don't know what the domain of the PDE (or is it an ODE?) should be.  Also, I don't know how to generalize the notion of a unit impulse.

Comment: (I have already understood all of Liggett Ch.2-3, so please feel free to use that if it makes answering my question easier, thanks.)